# Cut off the path of the working directory in the Linux console

Tags: bash, terminal, command-prompt

When I am getting into my working directory, I have the next pathname in the console:

```
kravcneger@kravcneger-X751L:~/projects/gcc/my_project
```

That path is very long, and it increases the width of the terminal window.
How can I make the pathname shorter, so that I wouldn't have to expand the terminal for comfortable work?
A critical condition: to change the machine name and the working directory is prohibited. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add (or change) in your `~/.bashrc` file `PS1` variable:

```
PS1='\h \W\$ '
```

Here, `\h` is the machine name, `\W` is the basename of the current directory, and `\$` is the literal `$`.

**SEE ALSO:**

[Controlling the Prompt (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Timur.
Can you give advice, how can I do a dynamic solution if it is even possible? 
For example, I would open a terminal, get into the working directory, and execute my bash command and get a new view, but in other terminal windows is staying the old look.

Comment: @kravcneger For terminal windows already open, execute the command in each terminal. For newly opened windows: (a) Add the above command to `~/.bashrc` file. Save the file. You only need to do it once. (b) Then every time you open a new terminal window, you will get the newly specified (shorter) prompt.